# Android Studio not responding

Tags: windows, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, android-sdk-manager

I updated Android Studio to v2.3.3 on Windows 10, now when I try to use the automated resolve button "Install Repository and sync project" Android Studio isn't responding anymore nor it installs the repository.

[image: Screenshot]

**Has anyone ever faced a similar issue? Is it an Android Studio problem or a Windows problem? How to solve it?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to tools, Android, SDK manager. Jump over to the SDK tools section and check the missing repository. You can click the "Show package details" to install the exact missing version. Hope this helps, was stuck here too but this helped me.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I can't seem to find the version selection for Google Play services [here](https://puu.sh/wHGGP/3f56c23e96.png). Is there another location where I can select the specific version?

Comment: Not that i know off. Are there updates pending in your android studio version?

Comment: No. I am just downloading Android Studio again and will see if that helps and fixed the problem.

Comment: All the best. Hope you've backed up your projects